# IOException while connecting to SMTP Service (Android)

Tags: java, android, smtp, apache-commons, ioexception

This is my class that I have created just to check whether SMTP Service is running or not on the specific port of the host. I am getting the IOException while trying to connect (I have mentioned that in the comment). Am I on the right track of doing this. Is there some other better methods to determine if the service is perfectly running or not in the host at specific port. I am using apache commons library for this.

```
import org.apache.commons.net.smtp.AuthenticatingSMTPClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class SmtpServiceTest {

    String hostaddress;
    Integer port;

    public SmtpServiceTest(String hostaddress, Integer port) {
        this.hostaddress = hostaddress;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public Boolean execute() {
        AuthenticatingSMTPClient client = null;

        try {
            client = new AuthenticatingSMTPClient();
            client.setDefaultTimeout(10 * 1000);
            // I get IOException on this line while trying to connect
            client.connect(hostaddress, port);

            // I am not sure about this too
            if (client.execTLS()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(client != null && client.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    client.logout();
                    client.disconnect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a message with the exception?

Comment: Post exception stack trace for better answer !!!